# Configure esplora to point to the bitcoind servers ip address - Part 2

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, ubuntu, blockexplorer

Continuing on from this post: [Configure esplora to point to the bitcoind servers ip address](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/91746/configure-esplora-to-point-to-the-bitcoind-servers-ip-address#)

Trying to run `cargo run --release --bin electrs -- -vvv --daemon-dir ~/.bitcoin`, but it kept saying that the `.cookie` file is missing.  I manually created the `.cookie` file with `user:pass` and I am now getting the following error message:

[image]

Any idea how to correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Address already in use"

It probably means you have another instance of the process running on the background