# Configure esplora to point to the bitcoind servers ip address - Part 3

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, ubuntu, blockexplorer

Continuing on from this post: [Configure esplora to point to the bitcoind servers ip address - Part 2](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/93498/configure-esplora-to-point-to-the-bitcoind-servers-ip-address-part-2)

Trying to run `cargo run --release --bin electrs -- -vvv --daemon-dir ~/.bitcoin`, but it kept saying `- reconnecting to bitcoind: no reply from daemon`.

The `bitcoin.conf` file has a `rpcuser` and `rpcpassword` set.  I have set the same `username:password` in in that format for the `.cookie` file for electrs.

Any idea why it's not connecting?

---

EDIT:

More details below:

[image]

I then create .cookie file in that location with the rpc username:password and then get this message: "no reply from daemon"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the following:

- do you use bitcoin rpc standard port for the network you are using? If not or not sure specify it explicitly with `--daemon-rpc-addr 127.0.0.1:8332`
- Are you sure the `.cookie` file is in the default position? Try the explicit option `--cookie username:password`
- Is bitcoind on the same machine? By default only rpc connection from localhost are allowed

If none of the above work, please post log from eletrs

Comment: How do I access the electrs logs?

Comment: copy and paste stdout

Comment: Further details added.

Comment: so I imagine /mnt/shared/.cookie file contains your rpcuser and rpcpassword, not sure what's happening, did you try to launch electrs with the explicit `--cookie RPCUSER:RPCPASSWORD` option?

Comment: `--cookie RPCUSER:RPCPASSWORD` worked, but it doesn't work in the `.cookie` file.  Thanks for the help.  Now I have another error.  Will create a new post for that.